# How to solve value difference between Formula Bar and Cell Value in Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm try to insert excel values into Database table using SSIS package creation

```
Formula Bar value = 7.96039603960396

Cell Value        = 7.96039604
```

In my Excel Sheet c10 cell value is 7.96039604.

If i click the A1 cell in formula bar it show me 7.96039603960396.

C1 to C9 values are empty.so I'm using IMEX=1 in Excel Connection string

In c10 cell I'm not using any Format cell its General only.

If i using **IMEX=1** in excel connection string in DB Table 7.96039604 is inserted.

but i need to insert 7.96039603960396 in DB Table

Answer (score 0):

Format the entire Excel Spreadsheet as text, then convert the text values to decimals of the required precision once the data is in SQL Server.

Excel => Temp Table or inline transformation => Destination Table.

Comment: I'm new to SSIS package creation. I'm not clear with your answer. please give more details. Thanks